# (De)Seralise the root node elements and diferent child elements

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have different type of xml files, below is one of example.
Xml tags are dynamically formed, I need to get the root tag Name and child tag names with values from xml file according to the hierarchy

```
<Employee>
<PersonalInfo>
  <Id>206</Id>
  <Name>Govinda</Name>
  <Skills>C#,ASP.NET,MVC4,HTML,CSS</Skills>
</PersonalInfo>
<Projects>
  <Working>
    <Name>Project306</Name>
    <Team>Team10</Team>
    <Role>Developer</Role>
  </Working>
  <Completed>
    <Name>Agro Seeds</Name>
    <Team>Team9</Team>
    <Role>Developer</Role>
  </Completed>
</Projects>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at XDocument? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: gone through it,but i unable to get the child nodes and values from the xml tags

Comment: Can you show some code that doesn't work, and perhaps we can tell you the problem.

Comment: got it with looping (foreach)

Answer (score 0):

```
 XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/employee.xml"));
        XmlElement root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;       
        string Content = string.Empty;           
        Content += "<div>" + root.Name;
        Content += "<ul>";
        foreach (XmlNode node in root)
        {
            Content += node.Name;
            for (int i = 0; i < node.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
            {
                Content += "<li>" + (node.ChildNodes[i]).Name + " : " + (node.ChildNodes[i]).InnerText + "</li>";
            }

        }
        Content += "</ul>";
        Content += "</div>";
```

Comment: can we achieve the same Using LINQ query